# How to fetch values from double mapping?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I have a structure **data** with double mapping for storing and fetching details. Here is the code :

```
struct data {
    uint a;
    uint b;
}
mapping(address => mapping(bytes11 => data[])) testidmapping;
```

Used **storevalues()** function to store and **getvalues()** to fetch the values

```
function storevalues(address owner,bytes11 id,uint a,uint b) public{
testidmapping[owner][id].push(data(a,b));
}

function getvalues(address owner,bytes11 id) view returns (uint a){
  data storage k = testidmapping[owner][id];
  return (k.a);

}
```

Is this the possible way of double mapping for fetching and storing details?
But I am getting this error:

> BigNumber() is not a number: (id is printing)

Help will be appreciated...

Comment: The error that you're describing sounds like an off-chain error (e.g., Javascript), but there is no off-chain code in your question.

Comment: Also, what is `data(a,b)` in function `storevalues`? Variables `a` and `b` are not defined anywhere!

Comment: Thank You...I just edited the code, passing the a and b values from javascript.
Basically I don't know how to fetching the values from double mapping from a structure?

Comment: You did not refer to my first comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you intended to access an attribute of an array`data[]` you shall provide an index. You might also need a length of an array `data` so that you can write a loop in backend code to retrieve all the `a`'s stored in an array data.

Refer the following function -

```
function getValuesAtIndex(address owner,bytes11 id,uint dataindex) view returns (uint a){

  return (testidmapping[owner][id][dataindex].a);

}

function getDataLength(address owner,bytes11 id)view returns(uint){

  return (testidmapping[owner][id].length);    
}
```

Hope it helps! Let me know if any further clarification is required.